# Left joined combined with inner join not returning all the rows from the left table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query where I have 2 inner joins and one left join. I want all the data from the left join table

My query looks like this:

```
select ordernumber,PartDescription,partNumber
from orders
inner join orderDetail on orders.orderID = orderDetail.orderID
left join parts on orderdetail.partID = parts.partID
inner join inventory on parts.partid = inventory.partid
```

However, this query only gives me a 5 or 6 rows instead of 100 rows that is in the parts table.

Comment: If you want all the rows from the `parts` table, you need a `RIGHT JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: What's this query supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix inner and left joins the result is not a left join.
Also since you want all the rows of the table `parts` make it the *left* table:

```
select o.ordernumber, p.PartDescription, p.partNumber
from parts p
left join inventory i on p.partid = i.partid 
left join orderdetail od on p.partID = od.partID
left join orders o on o.orderID = od.orderID
```

Use aliases for the table names, it makes the code easier to read.
Also qualify all the columns with the table name/alias.
I kept in the joins the table `inventory` although I don't see that it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting at the part table, and joining from there. Without any data, this is a best attempt:

```
select ordernumber, PartDescription, partNumber
from parts
    left join orderdetail on parts.partID = orderdetail.partID
    inner join orders on orders.orderID = orderDetail.orderID
    inner join inventory on parts.partid = inventory.partid
```

Comment: This gave me 8 rows instead of 5 rows but still did not give me all the data from the parts table

Comment: Can you show what columns are in each table, or an ER diagram please? This is not reproducible currently. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are inner joining parts with inventory that will only take the common data , hence reducing the no of rows. Try left join there too.